# Squeryl: left outer join for Option[Long] value

Tags: scala, playframework, squeryl

I'm trying to implement a request like in example in documentation:
http://squeryl.org/joins.html

I have a table "Requisite" and "Service". In field "paymentRequisite" of  table Service could be a link to row of Requisite or Null:

```
@Column("paymentRequisite")
var paymentRequisite: Option[Long],
```

I have a request like this:

```
inTransaction {
     join(AppDb.paymentRequisite, AppDb.catalogService.leftOuter)((p, c) => 
       compute(p.id, count(c.map(_.id))) 
       on(p.id === c.map(_.paymentRequisite))).toList
}
```

But this throws an exception:

```
[error]  found   : Option[Option[Long]]
[error]  required: org.squeryl.dsl.NumericalExpression[?]
```

It's because of `_.paymentRequisite`

Finally, what I'm trying to select ReqId and count of Services which reference to this requisite.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution =)

```
inTransaction {
     join(AppDb.paymentRequisite, AppDb.catalogService.leftOuter)((p, c) => 
       groupBy(p.id) 
       compute(p.id, count(c.map(_.id))) 
       on(Some(p.id) === c.flatMap(_.paymentRequisite))).toList
}
```